# making an char array out of string array

Tags: c#, linq, char

Here I have an array. I want to group them by their first letter, and then take out the strings that begins with a and b, char array them.

the following is my attempt:

```
 string[] ab = { "aa", "ab", "bb", "bc", "cd", "ce" };

var aq = ab.GroupBy(i => i[0]).Where(x => x.Key == 'a' && x.Key == 'b').SelectMany(x => x.Value.ToCharArray());
```

My Problem here is at my last statement, i cant get x.Value which is strange since it belongs to igroup

Also I would like to get a char array answer something like  { a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c}

Comment: You don't need `GroupBy` to do this.

Comment: Any input will be appreciated! also I want to understand the problem as well.

Comment: What do yo mean by "the strings that begins with a and b"? A string cannot begin with a *AND* b.

Comment: a char array of  { a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c} which comes from { "aa", "ab", "bb", "bc"}

Comment: Something like this?: `ab.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && (s[0] == 'a' || s[0] == 'b')).SelectMany(s => s).ToArray()`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want without a `GroupBy()`, by checking the first character of each string:

```
var result = ab
    .Where(x => x.ToLower()[0] == 'a' 
        || x.ToLower()[0] == 'b')
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToArray();
```

Please not this will break if you have any `null` values in your list.

You can also use the `StartsWith()` extension and pass in the boolean parameter to ignore case along with the culture info:

```
var result = ab
    .Where(x => x.StartsWith("a", true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) 
        || x.StartsWith("b", true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToArray();
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DRbJnh)

Comment: What if there is an empty string in the list?

Comment: Empty string should be fine, however a null will break the indexer.  However the same problem persists in the OP's code so I make the assumption that OP filters null values prior to applying this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var aq = ab.Where(it => it.StartsWith("a") || it.StartsWith("b"))
           .SelectMany(it => it.ToCharArray());
```

First you select the strings that start with 'a' OR 'b', then you turn them into char arrays and concatenate them.

Comment: `.ToCharArray()` is redundant and can be removed. `string` **is** `IEnumerable<char>`